# Final check when user Checkouts to compare cart qty vs database qty only returns one record even with multiple items in the cart

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check my entire cart array against the database when a user checkouts to make sure that they items in their cart are still actually available and another user didn't purchase the last of an item somewhere in between. But I am having a hard time trying to figure out getting more than one record. Before I even get to checking what is in the cart vs the database, I am just trying to get the quantities in the database for each product id at this stage.

Here is my controller that is just putting the data from the database call into the $totals variable.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['cart_array'])) {

    $response = array();

    $totals = $this->ProductFendModel->finalDbQtyCheckoutCheck();

    $response['cart'] = $totals;
    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

This is the database query in the model:

```
    $purchased = '0000-00-00';
    $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(`product_id`) as `vouchersLeft`, `product_id` FROM `vouchers` WHERE `product_id` = :product_id AND `purchased` = :purchased");
    $this->db->bind(":purchased", $purchased);
    $this->db->bind(":product_id", $prod_id);

    foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $cart) {
        $prod_id = $cart['prod_id'];
        $quantity = $cart['quantity'];
    }

    $results = $this->db->resultSet();
    return $results;
```

Whether I put $results in the foreach loop or where it is now, I only get back one result even though there are multiple items in the cart.

Comment: your loop in this format doesnt make any sense...

Comment: The loop is meant to check each item in the database with the product id. And I am trying to bind the product id in the loop when running the query.

Comment: _The loop is meant to check..._ The loop is doing basiucally **nothing** (than wasting memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constantly overwriting your $results variable with the last product you check. If you want to keep data for all the products in your cart you could store the information in an array. Something like this:

```
$purchased = '0000-00-00';
$this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(`product_id`) as `vouchersLeft`, `product_id` FROM `vouchers` WHERE `product_id` = :product_id AND `purchased` = :purchased");
$this->db->bind(":purchased", $purchased);
$this->db->bind(":product_id", $prod_id);

$results = [];

foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $cart) {
    $prod_id = $cart['prod_id'];
    $quantity = $cart['quantity'];
    $results[] = $this->db->resultSet();
}

return $results;
```

Now in your controller you could loop through the array and check if the amounts are still correct. (Or maybe you can do the check right in the function, you generally don't want to have too much logic in your controller)